# 画面を小さくした時に2つ目の画像が文章に重なってしまう。

Tags: css, html5

画面を小さくした時に2つ目の画像が文章に重なってしまう。
画像の隣に文章を表示する形で合計3つ縦に並べたいのですが画面を小さくした時に2つ目の画像が文章に重なってしまいます。どう修正すればよろしいでしょうか。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>あいうえお商店</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-timepicker.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style type="text/css">
    section{
      width: 80%;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    p{
       width: 45%;
    }
    img{
      width: 50%;
    }
    .right-p{
      padding-left: 5%;
      float: right;
    }
    .left-p{
      padding-right: 5%;
      float: left;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <section>
      <img src="GAZOU.JPG">
      <p class="right-p">1aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </p>
  </section>
  <section>
      <img src="GAZOU.JPG">
      <p class="left-p">2aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </p>
  </section>
  <section>
      <img src="GAZOU.JPG">
      <p class="right-p">3aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
        aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaavaaavaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
      </p>
  </section>
  <p>bbb</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p { word-wrap: break-word; }`
を追加することで単語の途中でも強制的に改行するようにすれば大丈夫です。

例示のためにアルファベットを羅列しているため、単語の区切りが判別できないことで生じています。